# AutoHotKey - Multiple commands not being executed

Tags: itunes, autohotkey, hotkeys

I am using an AutoHotKey script to control iTunes with standard media keys and its working great except for one tweak I've tried to add to it.  I want the Play/Pause media key to Launch iTunes if it's not open already and then just start playing.  I've even added a delay so it would have time to open before the play command.
This is the code I've tried but it just launches iTunes and I have to press the Play/Pause key a second time to start playing:

```
Media_Play_Pause::
IfWinNotExist, ahk_class iTunes
{
Run %ProgramFiles%\iTunes\iTunes.exe
Sleep, 4000
ControlSend, ahk_parent, {SPACE}  ; play/pause toggle
return
}

IfWinExist, ahk_class iTunes
{
ControlSend, ahk_parent, {SPACE}  ; play/pause toggle
return
}
```

EDIT:  Working code per [JJohnston2](https://superuser.com/users/500193/jjohnston2) answer below:

```
Media_Play_Pause::
IfWinNotExist, ahk_class iTunes
{
Run %ProgramFiles%\iTunes\iTunes.exe
WinWaitActive, ahk_class iTunes, ,2
Sleep, 2000
ControlSend, ahk_parent, {SPACE}  ; play/pause toggle
return
}

IfWinExist, ahk_class iTunes
{
ControlSend, ahk_parent, {SPACE}  ; play/pause toggle
return
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just glancing at the code, I don't see what window the first `ControlSend` is supposed to be sending to.  Designate a WinTitle, i.e., `ahk_class iTunes` for the third argument.

That, or instead of a sleep statement, try `WinWaitActive` (possibly followed by a much shorter `Sleep` statement if `WinWaitActive` doesn't fully do the trick).

A `WinWaitActive` statement would presumably set the last found window the same way `IfWInExist` does in the second block of code, which is the only reason I can think of that this actually works.  ControlSend must be sending to the last found window since none is specified explicitly.

Comment: haha!  someone in the ahk forum suggested `WinWait` and I got it working by inserting `WinWait, ahk_class iTunes, , 2`  before the `Sleep` statement.  I guess adding this statement is specifying a window for `ahk_parent` to send to?